# How to access child component form array values with-in parent componet in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How to access child component form array values with-in parent componet in Angular JS.

Example code

```
 parent
    <div [formGroup]="createForm">
        <div formArrayName="pFormArray">
          <div *ngFor="let pFormArray of pFormArrayArray.controls; let j=index" [formGroupName]="j">
            {{ j }}

                <app-child [pForm]="pForm"></app-child>
                <!-- </div> -->
              </p-accordionTab>
            </p-accordion>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

child
     <div class="ui-fluid" [formGroup]="pForm">


        <div class="ui-g ui-g-nopad" *ngFor="let sForm of sFormArray.controls; 
        index as i; first as isFirst"

        [formGroupName]="i">
         <input type="text" formControlName="name"> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfMKF.jpg)

Comment: So are you using Angular (the new framework) or AngularJS (the old one)? Please edit the tags and your title accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewChild` to get reference to your child component.

Try the following code

**parent.component.html**

```
<child #childRef></child>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('childRef') child : ChildComponent;

ngAfterViewInit(){
 console.log(this.child.getValue());
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
getValue(){
 return 'value';
}
```

Check out the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbheew)

Comment: This is work for one child component if we used.My case using both form arrays (multiple) child and parent. If we get like this @ViewChild('childRef') child : ChildComponent; only one child return. Do you have any idea ??. Thank you